# Is there such a thing as too many executors in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm working with a Spark/YARN cluster that limits the resources I can allocate to 8GB memory and 1 core per container, but I can allocate hundreds, perhaps even thousands of executors to run my application on.

However since the driver has similar resource limitations (8GB memory, 4 cores), I'm concerned that too many executors may overwhelm the driver and cause timeouts.

Is there a rule of thumb for sizing the driver memory and cores to handle large numbers of executors?

Answer (score 1):

There are rules on how to size your "executors".

For driver with 8GB and 4 core it should be able to handle thousands of executors easily as it only maintains bookkeeping metadata of the executors.

Given the assumption you are not having functions like collect() in your spark code.

Spark code analysis will help you to understand which actions in spark are performed where : http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-code-analysis/